# COMO OBTENER PATH DE UN SERVICIO?

Tags: vb.net, rutas, servicio, firebird

Estoy corriendo un servicio "Firebird Server - DefaultInstance" lo cualk es igual a "fb_inet_server.exe"
el problema viene al intentar ver su path ya que este cambia dependiendo de que arquitectura se instala,
ademas de que quiero evitar errores si el usuario se le ocurre mover el archivo de lugar.
para ello use esta parte de código (Process.GetProcessesByName("fb_inet_server.exe")), el problema es que me da nothig como resultado.

'''

```
 Try

    Dim firebird As ServiceController = New ServiceController("Firebird Server - DefaultInstance")
        Dim ruta_firebird As String = Nothing
        If firebird.Status <> ServiceControllerStatus.Running Then
            firebird.Start()
            firebird.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
            'pausa hasta que alcanza el estado
        End If
        Dim ps() As Process
        ps = Process.GetProcessesByName("fb_inet_server.exe")
        For Each p As Process In ps
            ruta_firebird = Replace(p.MainModule.FileName, "fb_inet_server.exe", "")
            Exit For
        Next
        If crear_bd(nombre_bd, ruta_firebird) Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        log(ex.Message)
        descargas() 'no cuenta con firebird, ejecuta instalación

    End Try
```

'''

Comment: comúnmente cuando llamas un GetProcessesByName no se coloca la extencion del programa. revisa en tu TaskManager o Adminitrador de tareas, el nombre del proceso Firebird, y tal cual esta el nombre asi lo debes de colocar en el GetProcessesByName.

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener la ruta donde se encuentra instalado el servicio, puedes valerte del valor almacenado en el registro de la máquina por el servidor mismo.

Encontrarás una entrada por cada instancia que está corriendo dentro de `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Firebird Project\Firebird Server\Instances`

El nombre de cada entrada es el nombre de la instancia, por ejemplo `DefaultInstance` y el valor es la ruta donde está instalado el Firebird que ejecuta esa instancia.

En mi caso, por ejemplo, tengo esto en mi equipo de desarrollo:

[image: Ruta de Firebird DefaultInstance]

Traducido a código, podría ser algo como:

```
ruta_firebird = My.Computer.Registry.GetValue(
    "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Firebird Project\Firebird Server\Instances", "DefaultInstance", Nothing)
If ruta_firebird Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox("No se encontró la ruta de Firebird.")
End If
```